# Unable to target netstandard or netstandardapp in VS2015

Tags: asp.net-core

Having a hell of a time finding information on this - pretty straight forward question.

I'm trying to target the new netstandard and netstandardapp monikers in an RC2 project and visual studio is telling me the frameworks are unsupported.  I see plenty of project.json files on GitHub using them...

Assuming I have to install something.

Please advise.

Comment: I suspect that you are suffering from [this bug](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/pull/3367). Could you run dnvm update-self and dnvm upgrade, restart VS and try again?

Answer (score 5):

The current public tooling doesn't understand the `netstandard*` monikers. We're working on new tooling as we speak. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: How to contrib to a aspnet 5 project on github when developing with Visual Studio ? They target netstandard1.3.

Comment: Its crazy I accepted this answer today, and at the same time Update 2 came out claiming to resolve this issue... alas it doesn't. 

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Any advice?  VS2015 is reporting Update 2 installed and Nuget 3.4.0

Comment: @user2069563 I believe the issue is that nuget added support for the netstandard moniker, but VS 2015 has yet to gain this support.